# Python returns [List[6:7]] but has to return [List[6], List[7]]

Tags: python, list, maya

I have only been using Python for a month.
In my maya python script I do some math with 2 vertices that are selected by the user. I get the position of the currently selected points:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.select(cmds.polyListComponentConversion(fe=True, tv=True))    # convert edge selection to vertex selection
print(cmds.ls(sl=True))    # print current selection

pp1 = cmds.pointPosition(cmds.ls(sl=True)[0], w=True)    # get position of selection[0], the first vertex
print("pp1: " + str(pp1))
pp2 = cmds.pointPosition(cmds.ls(sl=True)[1], w=True)   # get position of selection[1], the second vertex
print("pp2: " + str(pp2))
```

When the code works, this is what's printed to the log:

```
[u'pCube1.vtx[1]', u'pCube1.vtx[7]']
pp1: [7.2562560798528395, 18.23134491086187, 6.550243649783406]
pp2: [6.198982900492936, 12.856195407247569, -5.962323209376731]
```

When it does not work, this gets printed:

```
[u'pCube1.vtx[6:7]']
pp1: [-5.058764815898389, 7.64226049622069, -2.77127577531697]
# Warning: Only one item can be selected. Using the first selection.# 
# Error: IndexError: index out of range #
```

The problem is clear, a sliced list is returned for some reason. Why is it not returning [u'pCube1.vtx[6]', u'pCube1.vtx[7]'], like in the first example?

Comment: Please, provide an implementation of `cmds.ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about why `cmds.ls(sl=True)`, if two vertices are next to each other, it returns list with slice operator `[pCube1.vtx[5:6]]`. (maybe that's how it implemented)

One solution I'd suggest here to unpack the list when you get it like this,

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.select(cmds.polyListComponentConversion(fe=True, tv=True))  
print(cmds.ls(sl=True))  

vertex1, vertex2 = cmds.ls(sl=True)

pp1 = cmds.pointPosition(vertex1, w=True)    
pp2 = cmds.pointPosition(vertex2 , w=True)
```

Even if you get `cmds.ls(sl=True)` value as in this format `[pCube1.vtx[5:6]]`, the vertex values are unpacked to each variables.

**Illustration:**

```
>>> li = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> li[2:4]
[3, 4]
>>> a, b = li[2:4]
>>> a
3
>>> b
4
```

**Update:**

```
>>> li = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> li[2:3]
[3]
>>> a, b = li[2:3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    a, b = li[2:3]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
>>>
```

Comment: When trying to unpack,, I get an Error: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: In python list slicing ```li[ start_index : end_index ]```, it won't include element at ```end_index``` .  In your case, you getting only one value ```[pCube1.vtx[5:6]]```. Updated illustration.

Comment: The "slice" is not really a Python list slice, but a notation used by maya to describe adjacent indices. It's not uncommon to see two ranges: `[u'pCube.vtx[10:20]', u'pCube.vtx[30:40]']`